# Using List.exists, List.for_all, and List.filter together in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to filter a list of user-defined types by the contents of a list within those types, and I was wondering if there's a way to use `List.filter`, `List.exists`, and `List.for_all` to reach that inner list instead of making a function to reach it.

```
type weight = int
type height = int 
type colours = Red | Black | Orange | White
type cat = Cat of weight * height * colours list

let cat1 = Cat (14, 14, [Red; Black])
let cat2 = Cat (15, 20, [Black; White])
let cat3 = Cat (13, 15, [Red; White])
let cats =  [cat1; cat2; cat3]
```

Is there a way to create a list of cats that aren't a certain colour using only these List functions? This is a homework question so I can't really include my code, but I added a function to isolate the list of colours within the type and then compared those lists

Thank you!

Comment: The type definition of cats doesn't fit your match statement. I edited it out, please tell me if it was intended otherwise.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x  thank you! The type definitions are included just to give an idea of the problem, and aren't the actual ones I'm working with; I'm just stuck on how to compare lists within types within a list of those types

Comment: I'm going to edit this to make it more conceptually based: it's a homework question

Comment: Then i'll post the full answer tomorrow but give you a hint today

Comment: @lambda.xy.x thank you; I'm confused about what parameters the List functions take when they're nested inside each other

Comment: It's mostly a matter of parenthesis. The first argument of all three functions is the predicate (of type `'a -> bool`), the second is a list. `List.filter (fun x -> List.mem x [1;2;3]) [2;3;4]` is just the same as `let check x = List.mem x [1;2;3] in List.filter check [2;3;4]`.

Comment: If you are unsure about nested function arguments, try writing them as `let`s first and change them to lambdas later.

Comment: Just to leave a comment: I also edited the examples - careful with , vs ; in lists. The first creates a tuple, the second one seperates list elements. ( `[1,2,3] = [(1,2,3)]` ).

Comment: @lambda.xy.x thank you for the tip about `let`s first! That's really helpful. And thank you for catching another error... I'm still getting used to Ocaml's slightly different syntax

Comment: No worries, everyone has to start somewhere :)

Comment: Full solution is in :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pattern match the function applied to filter. To find all cats that are not black or that have weight < 14 you could use:

```
utop # List.filter (function Cat (_,_,cat_colors) ->
                             List.for_all (fun x -> x != Black)
                             cat_colors ) cats ;;
- : cat list = [Cat (13, 15, [Red; White])]


utop # List.filter (function Cat (weight,_,_) -> weight < 14) cats ;;
- : cat list = [Cat (13, 15, [Red; White])]
```

The rest should be doable with two applications `List.for_all` (as a logical formula: ∀c1 : colors ∀c2 : cat_cols. c1 ≠ c2 ). Hover over the spoiler block to reveal the full solution:

> `let choose colors =
>        List.filter (function Cat (_,_,catcols) ->
>           List.for_all (fun col ->
>               List.for_all ((!=) col) catcols) colors )`